# Displaying checkbox with selected element as checked

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I'm trying to let a user pick hobbies from list of hobbies that is provided in the form of checklist.  When they are chosen, chosen hobbies goes into the user table.  I would like for my checkbox to display the user's hobbies, as if the hobbies is selected, it is checked and if not its not checked.  User can update their hobbies by checking or unchecking the checkbox.
I'm having trouble displaying the current state of user hobbies in checked or unchecked form and updating the user hobbie table from it.

```
class InfoPage(BasePage):
    title = 'One Macnica'

  def get(self):
    self.write_page_header()

    hobbies_list = Hobby.all().fetch(100)



    template_values = {"hobbies_list": hobbies_list}
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
    path = os.path.join(path, 'hobby.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
    self.write_page_footer()

  def post(self):

    self.write_page_header()

    hobbies_list = Hobby.all().fetch(100)


    if self.request.get("hobby"):
      hobby_name = self.request.get('hobby')
      new_hobby = Hobby(name=hobby_name.strip(), key_name = hobby_name.strip())

      #fetch attendee and add new hobby
      attendee_query = Attendee.gql('WHERE email = :1',
          users.get_current_user().email())
      attendee = attendee_query.fetch(1)
      attendee = attendee.pop()
      hobbies = attendee.hobbies
      hobbies.append(new_hobby.key())
      attendee.hobbies = hobbies
      #eliminate the dupliate
      hobbies = list(set(hobbies))
      attendee.hobbies = hobbies
      attendee.put()



    template_values = {"hobbies_list": hobbies_list}
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
    path = os.path.join(path, 'hobby.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
    self.write_page_footer()
```

hobby.html is the following

```
<h1 id="header">One Macnica</h1>
<p>Welcome to One Macnica, a place dedicated to connecting Macnica as 1.
</p>
<form name="hobby" action="/hobby" method="post">


{% for hobby in hobbies_list %}
   <input type="checkbox" name = "{{hobby.name}}"/>{{hobby.name}}<br/>
{% endfor %}


<input type="submit" value="Select Hobbies">
</form>
```

i'm currently thinking of making a list for hobby checklist which compares all the hobby list to attendee's hobby list and if it there, return checked and if not return null. 
i'm having trouble actually coding this and dont know if this is the best way.

any help would be appreciated it.

Comment: Which template language are you using here?

Comment: i am using django that is in the GAE

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for hobby in hobbies_list %}
  <input type="checkbox" {% if hobby in user.hobbies %}checked="yes"{% endif %} name = "{{hobby.name}}"/>{{hobby.name}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve.  I tried that and I get 
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: 'yes' if hobby in attendee.hobbies else ''

Comment: Sorry I thought that was ok syntax in django templates, but it must be specific to jinja2. Use this slightly uglier syntax, `{% if hobby in user.hobbies %}checked="yes"{% endif %}`.

Comment: I tried it and i got TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted.   
i have also tried to take the if out of the <input> like
    {% for hobby in hobbies_list %}
      {% if hobby in attendee.hobbies %}
       <input type="checkbox" checked= "yes" name = "{{hobby.name}}"/>{{hobby.name}}<br/>

       {% endfor %}
       <input type="checkbox"  name = "{{hobby.name}}"/>{{hobby.name}}<br/>

    {% endfor %}
i still get same error.....  aaa

Comment: Put that code in a pastebin and throw the link up here so we can see it all formatted nicely. Off the top of my head I would point out that I don't see a closing `{% endif %}` tag, but I'm not sure there was just an issue with the pasting into the comment area. If you do put any code in the comment area you can put it in backticks (`) to make it display nicer among other text (monospace font and background).

Comment: Thanx Steve,  
http://pastebin.com/8PpfpQXM
i think the problem is using in in the if statement.. maybe? 
but i dont know how to go around it.

Comment: And you're still getting the same `TemplateSyntaxError`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a forms library, like Django forms or WTForms. There's no need to write large amounts of form handling code when it's already been done for you.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will look into those.

Comment: I would love to know who voted this down, and why. It's constructive to leave a comment if you think an answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for "checked" attribute (rest is as Steve answered):

```
checked={{ hobby in user.hobbies and "checked" or "" }}
```

**UPDATE:**

I haven't used that template engine for a long time. I believe it's because you can't use `in`,`and`,`or` inside `{{ }}`.

Uglier workaround would be:

```
checked={% if hobby in user.hobbies %}"checked"{% else %}""{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps.